# Flatpak is getting a lot of storage

Tags: flatpak, storage

As I remember, eOS5 was such a gracious operating system that you could rely on for doing any kind of daily work. Odin is better for sure but some things like Flatpak are annoying. I installed Odin with 31 GB of space I thought it will be enough but now after 3 months the Flatpak is increasingly filling the storage and I am not sure even I should clean it up myself. I had the same applications on Hera with 20 GB, I can say it was doing well.
How can I perform a clean-up for this purpose?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What Flatpack lovers don't tell you is that you can have three small apps, like baobab, for example, each maintained by the developer in a different GNOME environment, so the first app is using "GNOME Application Platform version 40" as a repo, the second one is using "GNOME Application Platform version 41" and the third is using "GNOME Application Platform version 3.36".

This "brilliantly" results in three apps, with .deb versions having just a few MB's combined, taking up about 1.5GB of your drive since you have to install all those environments to get them. It's like you need a small KDE app and you end up with the full KDE environment.

Long live Flatpak!

Comment: I am not technically an expert I had this environment with eOs5 just with 20 gigabytes and yet I have 50 gigabytes storage which is not enough! Everything they say I just see eOs is ruined I will go for Zorin or Pop os.